# AWS AccessDenied when calling sts:AssumeRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to allow a set of users in a group access to a role through which they can upload objects to an s3 bucket.

The group as the policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/Clinic_Sync"
    }
}
```

The role "Clinic_Sync" has the policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SyncReqs",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SyncReqs2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The bucket has the policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/Clinic_Sync"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mydata"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/Clinic_Sync"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mydata/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mydata",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mydata/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userId": [
                        "ADMINUSERID:*",
                        "ACCOUNTNO"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The idea being that no one can access the bucket except through assuming this role (other than the admin). I have created the credentials files as follows:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ACCESSID1
aws_secret_access_key = SECRETKEY1
[csync]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/Clinic_Sync
source_profile = default
```

And the config file:

```
[default]
output = json
region = eu-west-2
[profile csync]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/Clinic_Sync
source_profile = default
```

The bucket policy seems to work, as running the command "aws s3 cp hello.txt s3://mydata" gives the error: Upload failed. An error occured when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied.

But when I try to use the role, using the command "aws s3 cp hello.txt s3://run3d-data --profile csync", it gives this error:

```
upload failed: .\hello.txt to s3://mydata/hello.txt An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:user/TestAcc2 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/Clinic_Sync
```

I've been searching the web for an answer for ages and can't find any answers. The aws documentation is frankly unintelligible to me. If anyone can help me find a solution to this I'd be much appreciated as I'm tearing my hair out here.

To reiterate, I just want the users in a particular group to have access to a role that grants them permission to use an s3 bucket, but block all other access to the bucket.

Comment: And your `TestAcc2` user is part of the group?

Comment: Yes it definitely is

Answer (score 1):

Your bucket policy seems to say: "Deny access to the bucket unless `aws:userId` is a given Admin User ID or Account Number. It does not reference the Role.

Therefore, accessing the bucket via the Role will be denied. This is because Deny always overrides Allow.

Writing policies with Deny can be quite difficult, as seen in this situation.

If you really want to keep a bucket secure, it is easier to **put the bucket in a separate AWS Account** and only grant cross-account access to the entities that should have access. This way, no Deny policy is required.

---

If you receive a `not authorised to perform sts:AssumeRole` error, make sure the Trust Policy grants access to users by selecting the **Another AWS account** option when creating the role. The policy should look similar to:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: My bucket does reference the role. The first 2 statements are specific to the role. And everything I've read so far seemed to suggest writing an allow statement as I've done will overwrite the deny statement (pls correct me if that's wrong). Also I don't see how that 'fix' will affect the specific error I'm getting, which is to do with allowing my user TestAcc2 to assume the role Clinic_Sync...

Comment: A `Deny` will override any `Allow`. See: [Determining whether a request is allowed or denied within an account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-denyallow)

Comment: Oh I see what you mean! You mean the Deny doesn't specifically reference the role. Ahh. Sorry if I seem to be pushing back, I'm just trying to understand stuff! And thanks for the flow chart. Very useful!

Comment: Correct. It can be very hard to say "Deny everything, unless they come from this role OR the are an Admin OR...". That's why it's best to only Allow what should be permitted in the first place. If that is too hard, sometimes using a separate account makes it easier (eg for sensitive data such as HR information).

Comment: Okay, I've fixed that, by removing the deny statement and just including my admin account in the allow statements. I'm still getting the "not authorised to perform sts:AssumeRole" error though. Is there anything I could have missed? I've noticed there are trust policies attached to the role (mine only allows s3 to do assume role). Could that be the problem?

Comment: The `not authorised to perform sts:AssumeRole` error suggests that they either do not have `AssumeRole` permissions (but your policy seems to grant that), _OR_ the role does not have the correct Trust configuration. When creating the role, select **Another AWS account** and enter the Account ID (even if it is for the _same_ account). This will create a **Trust Policy** that points to the root of the account, meaning that any authorized user in the account can assume the role. I'll add a sample Trust Policy to my answer.